# Rounding to Nearest Even Number in C++

Tags: int, rounding

I was wondering if C++ included a way to round to the nearest even number. I've looked around and I can't seem to find anything on the subject. I could write my own method, but using a built-in one would most likely be faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Its a floating point value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this. The most straightforward way might be to do something like:

```
even = round(x / 2) * 2;
```

Comment: Thats exactly how I was doing it. Thanks.

Comment: But you can only deal with 0.5 with this case, when you round 1, you got 2 but expected 1.

Comment: @Yimu, the question is about rounding to nearest even number.  When you round 1, you would expect 2.

Comment: @Xavier, thank you! May be there is another question that round half to even but not affect other rounding [wiki: Round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)

Comment: To clarify, "round to nearest even" is a form of rounding to nearest where 0.5 goes toward the nearest even number but otherwise is the same as "round to nearest up" where 0.5 goes to the higher number. The question is ambiguous on whether this sense is meant.

Answer (score 8):

As said before, there is no builtin way. So let's see a few ways this can be done. But first...

Performance Caveats:

- Avoid division, as it's still slow for floats, although not as bad as it is for integers. Multiplication is nearly as fast as addition for floats.
- Multiplication by 2 <sup>-x</sup> for any whole x is guaranteed to be equivalent to
  division by 2 <sup>x</sup>, while not losing precision.
- Make all constants the same type to prevent promotion, especially when the value is just going to be stored in the same type again.

### Simple

`std::round( x * 0.5f ) * 2.0f`

This will round away from zero at every odd number, creating a small bias.

In general, avoid [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) if possible. It's slow due to the fact that it must: save the rounding mode, switch it, round, and then restore the previous rounding mode. All so that it can introduce bias.

### Magic Numbers

Pre C++11, we can use magic numbers to alleviate the bias by using the builtin banker's rounding. **Warning:** this relies on the rounding mode being the default ([`FE_TONEAREST`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round)), which it usually is 99.9999% of the time, but be wary of other libraries potentially changing it and not restoring it afterward.

`float` Magic: `( x + 25165824f ) - 25165824f`

This uses the fact that the floating point precision is only so many bits. By adding a magic number that's large enough, the lowest bits we don't want will be rounding automatically, after which we subtract our magic number, leaving our original rounded to the correct precision.

The magic number is calculated as 1.5 * 2 <sup>**p**</sup> where **p** is the precision of the float point significand: 24 for `float`, 53 for `double`, and 64 for `long double`. With a little help from `std::numeric_limits` we can make this generic.

```
template< typename T >
T magic_round_to_even( T x ) {
  static T magic = 1.5 * std::pow( 2.0L, std::numeric_limits< T >::digits);
  return ( x + magic ) - magic;
}
```

By changing **p** for our magic number we can round to different powers of two. **p** - 1 will create the standard banker's rounding.

### C++11

All hail the new way to round: [`std::nearbyint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint). This obeys the current rounding mode, so if the rounding mode's been twiddled with by something else, we can use [`std::fesetround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) to restore it to `FE_TONEAREST`.

`std::nearbyint( x * 0.5f ) * 2.0f`

This is as intuitive as the first version, but without any bias.

Comment: *Avoid division, as it's still slow for floats* - The compiler can optimize `x / 2.0f` and `x * 0.5f` to the same thing.  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YTm7zu

Comment: If you are using nearbyint, no need to do multiplications.. If you assume FE_TONEAREST, the result is simply std:nearbyint(x). FE_TONEAREAT is round to even.

Comment: @AllanJensen, FE_TONEAREST is *round to nearest with tie to even*, not *round to even*. So you do need multiplications.

Comment: Be advised: as written, the "Magic Numbers" approach only works for positive numbers.