# How to convert a Unix epoch time to a Pascal TDateTime(double) in C++

Tags: c++, unix, time, unix-timestamp

Following on from this [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625006/how-to-convert-a-pascal-tdatetimedouble-time-to-a-unix-epoch-in-c/67626489?noredirect=1#comment119551422_67626489) I need to do the conversion in the reverse direction (Unix Time to TDateTime).

@Howard Hinnant did a very elegant example using his date.h library but due to a compilation issue, I decided not to use it. His effort is appreciated though.

Could someone provide me with an example based on the code developed by @Remy Lebeau, please?

Comment: see this : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.UnixToDateTime

Comment: I'm using VS2019 so don't have access to it as mentioned in the comments of the previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This direction is easier than the other one. Here is a way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double UnixToDateTime(__int64 epoch)
{
    int days = epoch / (24*3600);
    int secs = epoch % (24*3600);
    return 25569 + days + ((double)secs)/(24*3600);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%.12f", UnixToDateTime(1060041720));
}
```

Output:

```
37838.001388888886
```