# Using the Date.h library how do I convert sys_seconds to time_t type

Tags: c++, time

I'm experimenting with the code provided by @Howard Hinnant in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625006/how-to-convert-a-pascal-tdatetimedouble-time-to-a-unix-epoch-in-c/67626489?noredirect=1#comment119551422_67626489) which uses his excellent `Date.h` library. I've renamed the functions to DateTimeToUnix and UnixToDateTime so that it is compatible with my existing code. However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
E0413   no suitable conversion function from "date::sys_seconds" to "const time_t" exists
```

on the following code line:

```
const time_t time_now = lib::DateTimeToUnix(TimeCurrent());
```

TimeCurrent() is an external function (Pascal) and returns a double TDateTime type.

The question is, how do I convert the output type of sys_seconds to time_t? I noticed that the library chrono has a `to_time_t` function but I'm not sure how to use it as I've no previous experience of using the chrono features.

I'm using the latest version of VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work:

```
const time_t time_now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(lib::DateTimeToUnix(TimeCurrent());
```

Comment: That will do it.