# How to do vector(simd) round to nearest, ties / half to even in ARMv7 by NEON efficiently?

Tags: c++, floating-point, arm, simd, neon

I am porting an ARMv8 targeting algorithm to ARMv7 platform. ARMv8 support vector convert from floating-point to signed or unsigned integer with directed rounding modes, `VCVT` with directed. Such round to nearest, ties to even SIMD `cvt` is heavily used in the origin ARMv8 target code, like `vcvtaq_u32_f32` and `vcvtnq_s32_f32`.

However, in ARMv7, we just cannot use these instruction, though ARMv7 scalar rounding support rounding mode specification(by set FPSCR), the NEON version `vcvt` just use round towards zero. I have to find a way to implement those vector round to nearest, ties / half to even in ARMv7.

One dummy way might be to extract single float from the source `qX` NEON register and adopt scalar rounding by manually setting FPSCR or using gcc's `roundevenf` one by one, then pack them back to a NEON register.

The above way is inefficient and dirty. So i wonder if there's some arithmetic way to implement this. I've checked [Rounding to Nearest Even Number in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464146/rounding-to-nearest-even-number-in-c), which used

```
even = round(x / 2) * 2;
```

And i do it in ARMv7 neon as below, add 0.5 to perform the `round` operation.

```cpp
int32x4_t round2even(float32x4_t x){
    return vshlq_n_s32(vcvtq_s32_f32(vmlaq_n_f32(vdupq_n_f32(0.5f), x, 0.5f)), 1);   
}
```

However, as the origin OP said, the solution is rounding to nearest even number, not ties to even. Resulting that 1.1 -> 2.0, which is not what i want.

So my question is, How to do vector(SIMD) round to nearest, ties / half to even in ARMv7 by NEON efficiently?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with NEON, but you could do something like `float two23 = 1<<23; y=abs(x); y=y<two23 ? (y + two23) - two23 : y; result = int(copysign(y, x));` -- if you know the sign of your values before, or know that their absolute value is below `1<<23`, you can skip some steps, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, i've tried the c code, it could work. Though the conditional execution might not be able to implement easily within my ability. Could your give more information about the bit magic here?

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with NEON. There should be some compare instruction which results in a bitmask which can then be used with something like a blend-operation or a set of bit-notand/bit-and/bit-or operations

Comment: What i mean is why can these code do round to nearest, ties to even

Comment: This works under the assumption that addition rounds to nearest. And since all floats between `2^23 <= y < 2^24` are perfect integers (and vice versa), if `x<2^23`, then `y=x+2^23` gets rounded to the nearest (ties to even) integer. If you know for sure that `0<=x<2^23` you could even directly extract the lowest 23 bits from y (and avoid the branch).

Comment: Surprisingly even for scalar, GCC/clang don't inline `lrintf()` or `(int)nearbyint` even at `-O3 -ffast-math`. https://godbolt.org/z/hG78Yc77h  And for AArch64, GCC vectorizes `nearbyint` but not `lrintf`.